# S#arp Architecture 1.9 + Fluently.Configure() NHiberbante

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I have a need to fluently configure nhibernate in my S#arp application so that I can use a custom NHibernate.Search directory for each of my tenants in a multi-tenant app.

However I have googled for hours looking for a solution but can't seem to find anything current that works.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: NHibernateSession.AddConfiguration won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but AddConfiguration takes a dictionary of cfgProperties, which I guess you can pass the tenant specific hibernate.search.default.indexBase value to.

I had a look at this, adding the key as described above will cause a problem if you attempt to use CfgHelper.LoadConfiguration() since it will return null.

But you can configure NHSearch to use different directories for each factory using the factory key:

```
  <nhs-configuration xmlns="urn:nhs-configuration-1.0">
    <search-factory sessionFactoryName="YOUR_TENANT1_FACTORY_KEY">
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">~\IndexTenant1</property>
    </search-factory>
    <search-factory sessionFactoryName="YOUR_TENANT2_FACTORY_KEY">
      <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">~\Tenant2</property>
    </search-factory>   
  </nhs-configuration>
```

If you are following instructions on
http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/Default.aspx?Page=NHibSearch
You would need to change the method GetIndexDirectory to

```
  private string GetIndexDirectory() { 
    INHSConfigCollection nhsConfigCollection = CfgHelper.LoadConfiguration(); 
    string factoryKey = SessionFactoryAttribute.GetKeyFrom(this); // Change this with however you get the factory key for your tenants,
    string property = nhsConfigCollection.GetConfiguration(factoryKey).Properties["hibernate.search.default.indexBase"];
    var fi = new FileInfo(property); 
    return Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fi.Name); 
}
```